# Can "launch" be used in the middle voice?

Tags: passive-voice

Usually it is used in the passive voice.

> The project **was launched** yesterday.

But I remember coming across something like

> The project **launched** yesterday.

Do you think that 2 is also correct?

Comment: See examples of 2 at: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/launch_1

Comment: What is this middle voice? The second example is active.

Comment: The middle voice is when you have the active voice meaning the passive.